# a:visited links not following CSS rules

Tags: css, hyperlink, rules

This is a problem that I've been having for quite some time now. For some reason, the CSS rules for my links aren't working properly. As far as I can tell, when using Chrome's Inspect Element tools or FireBug, the links appear to be styled correctly, but are displayed improperly. I've added separate classes to make separate styles of links, and even tried separating a:visited, and this fixed the basic issue for each class, but the normal a tag still displays visited links the wrong color. the CSS for my links has been below.

```
    a:link, a:hover, a:active
    {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #FF8C00;
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    a:visited
    {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #FF8C00;
        background-color: transparent !important;
    }
    a.search:link, a.search:visited, a.search:hover, a.search:active
    {
        font-family: helvetica-light;
        font-size: 19px;
        color: #999;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    a.nav:link, a.nav:visited,  a.nav:active, a.nav:hover
    {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #E3E3E3;
        font-family: helvetica-light;
        font-size: 20px;
        background-color: transparent;
    }
```

For some reason, even though a:link/etc have "color: #FF8C00" they show up as black or dark gray when visited. Active, link and hover all work normally. All HTML is written as     `<a href="url">stuff</a>`

Comment: Please post the corresponding HTML

Comment: Your css seems to work as I understand the question. I did change the visited color to red to be sure, but when I click on the normal link it turns red. http://jsfiddle.net/kTGMc/ (You have to open the jsfiddle link in a new tab to see the results.)

Comment: Ed, the HTML that's breaking is the standard `<a>` tag (`<a href="url">stuff</a>`). BNL's link to jsfiddle shows the same issue. I'm not sure if the a.class declaration for link, hover, visited and active are breaking the normal link tag but if I don't define a class to a link it will display the wrong color when it's been visited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution to my own problem. I had initially copied elements of my CSS from an older project I was working on. Somehow, an "a:visted" declaration had ended up inline with an ID declaration and didn't break the CSS, but caused the links to not appear properly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing;

```
color: #999;
```

Into;

```
color: #999 !important;
```

This will tell the CSS parser to overwrite the #FF8C00 color to #999.
Changing the order of the CSS blocks could also give you the expected result.

Sometimes getting the look you want might require some trial and error. :)

Comment: !important is a crutch for having improper styles. There is almost always a better answer.

Comment: I'd like to avoid using CSS cheats, especially when you assign classes. I don't want my `<a>` tags taking on the properties of classes, which is what will happen when I use !important;

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you could try

- clear your browser cache
- Make sure no other css files are been called
- Go to w3c html validation site